# Calling a function once mouse is released from colorpicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js

I spent whole day to find solution but it didn't help out. So basically, I want to call a function once a mouse is released from color picker. oninput seems to call function everytime I slide or click on color picker, this caused a performance issue while updating knockout observable. I also tried other refrences which used mouse events http://jsfiddle.net/b1Lzo60n/ http://jsfiddle.net/7yvfkcdn/ but it didn't help out.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="color" oninput="updateSelectedLabelColor(value)" data-bind="value: KnockoutWrapper.SelectedLabel().FontColour" />
</body>
</html>

<script>
function updateSelectedLabelColor(value) {
            TicketWrapper.SelectedLabel().FontColour(value);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try onmouseup event?

Comment: Yes I did, on mouseup is trigged when clicking color picker button but not while selecting color

Comment: Why not use the onchange event?

Comment: on change event does not work with input with type color

Comment: onchange event works, but it calls only when the color is picked and clicked outside. I need something which calls function while selecting color within colorpicker

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color):

> As is the case with other  types, there are two events that can
> be used to detect changes to the color value: input and change. input
> is fired on the  element every time the color changes. The
> change event is fired when the user dismisses the color picker. In
> both cases, you can determine the new value of the element by looking
> at its value.

So if you want to get the color value *before* the user dismisses the color picker, you need to use the `input` event. If you find this event fires too often and causes performance issues, you should debounce the event so it doesn't fire too often:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.color = ko.observable('#ff0000');
    vm.updateColor = _.debounce(function(data, event) {
      vm.color(event.target.value);
    }, 500);
}
```

So what does is it makes sure the `updateColor` function isn't called more than once every 500ms. You can of course increase or decrease the rate as needed.

I used Lodash in this example, but it's easy enough to implement if you don't have Lodash in your project.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/kqs96vfj/)